# What is the '\' operator in the C language?

Tags: c

The example that I am looking at is like this:

```
#define CONTROL_MEM_SIZE    ((CONTROL_ITEM_SIZE * CONTROL_QUEUE_SIZE) +   \
                            portQUEUE_OVERHEAD_BYTES)
```

I haven't seen the '\' operator. What is this?

Comment: It's not an operator, it's an escape sequence: backslash-newline.

Comment: This `\\` use in many languages for same purpose(to break you sentence in multiple lines), for example in Python, Java, JavaScript.

Answer (score 10):

It's not an operator, really.  It's just a line extension - it tells the preprocessor that the `#define` replacement text continues on the next line of the file.

Check out #3 at [this link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/cpp/Initial-processing.html):

> Continued lines are merged into one long line.
>   A continued line is a line which ends with a backslash, `\`. The backslash is removed and the following line is joined with the current one.

Comment: Thanks, Is it gonna be something wrong without '\'? like          #define CONTROL_MEM_SIZE        ((CONTROL_ITEM_SIZE * CONTROL_QUEUE_SIZE) + portQUEUE_OVERHEAD_BYTES)

Comment: Not if you put it on a single line, no.

Answer (score 3):

#### The `\` character at the end of a line is a [*line continuation*](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/38985/).

It tells the preprocessor to ignore the newline and consider the following line as part of this one.

Compare to the [VBScript `_` line continuation character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[C11 p5.1.1.2: Translation phase 2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2)

> Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines. [...]