# What is this syntax in C?

Tags: c, syntax

I am looking at the library of Nordic micro and see this syntax that I never saw before. Can anyone explain what is this syntax?

```
/**@brief Macro for setting the TX transfer descriptor. */
#define NRF_DRV_TWI_XFER_DESC_TX(addr, p_data, length)                 \
    {                                                                  \
        .type = NRF_DRV_TWI_XFER_TX,                                   \
        .address = addr,                                               \
        .primary_length = length,                                      \
        .p_primary_buf  = p_data,                                      \
    }
```

Is this a macro for struct in C? What is the use of "\"?

Comment: An answer for "\": https://stackoverflow.com/q/17495273/10077

Comment: '\' is canceling the new-line because a `#define` can only be a single line.

Comment: it's how you initialize the fields of a structure.

Comment: @FredLarson I see I'm not the only one having trouble with wrapping '\' in back-tics.

Comment: @Barmar but doesn't you need to define a struct first before you can initialize it?

Comment: Yes. Look for the place where the macro is used, it will be part of a variable initialization.

Comment: Like `struct something somevar = NRF_DRV_TWI_XFER_DESC_TX(...);`

Comment: ok I found that later in the code but I thought you need to explicitly define NRF_DRV_TWI_XFER_DESC_TX(...) as an instance of a struct before you can set it to another instance of the same struct?

Comment: `NRF_DRV_TWI_XFER_DESC_TX(...)`, being a macro, will be treated as a textual (well token, but not worth getting into the difference in this context) replacement.  It is not, itself, an instance of a struct, but rather it becomes the code that will make up a designated initializer.